# Magento: Stop domain redirect with multistores

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I'm currently trying to set up multistores for a magento site on our dev site.

I have two stores, the main store and the french store, with the following domain setup:

main store: `main.devsite.com`

french store: `mainfr.devsite.com`

I have a vhost set up for `main.devsite.com`. In this vhost, I have set up a `serverAlias` for `mainfr.devsite.com`.

Then, within the index.php I have the following code snippet.

```
$serverName = explode('.',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
if($serverName[0] == "mainfr") {
    mage::run("fr", "website");
} else {
    Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
}
```

The problem I have here is that magento  seems to automatically redirect `mainfr.devsite.net` to `main.devsite.net` when `Mage::run()` is called.

Is there a way to stop this happening?

Comment: Did you add store and website in magento backend ... System > Manage Stores? and have you set your stores' base urls both got secure and insecure? should just work at the moment all request is being taken to the default site I think

Comment: Problem solved! you were correct, the base urls weren't set up for the french site in the magento admin. it works fine now, thanks for your help!

Comment: ok I will add to the answer that for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add store and website in magento backend ... System > Manage Stores and set your stores' base urls both got secure and insecure? should just work at the moment all request is being taken to the default site I think